# attribute error : Image object has no attribute T

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am doing 8by8 block dct conversion through python.
There's error like the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'T'
```

here are some part of my code:

```
from scipy.fftpack import dct
from PIL import Image
import glob

def dct_2(img):
    #Get 2D Cosine Transform of Image

    return dct(dct(img.T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')

images = image_open(path)

for i in range(0, len(images)): 
    box3 = (1,1,256,256)
    a = images[i].crop(box3)
    width , height = a.size  

    (y,cb,cr) = a.split()  

    for q in range(1, height-32 , 32):  
        for w in range(1 , width-32 ,32):
            box1 =(q,w,q+63,w+63)
            block = y.crop(box1)

            for j in range(1,64,8):
                for n in range(1,64,8):
                    box2 = (j,n,j+7,n+7)
                    temp = block.crop(box2)

                    dct_temp = dct_2(temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the image object to an array before applying a transpose.

```
import numpy as np

def dct_2(img):
    #Get 2D Cosine Transform of Image
    return dct(dct(np.asarray(img).T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
```

Comment: I am novice here and I don't know how to mark question as completed. Is there any complete button here? or just write title as completed? I don't know but if I knew the way , I will mark. thanks